# Building representation of an arbitrary umbral calculus

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, functional-equations, umbral-calculus

Consider a set of integrable functions on the interval $(0,1)$.

Let's introduce an operation $\operatorname{eval}f=\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ (which is the mean value of the function).

In such system the function $f(x)=x$ will play the role of an umbra with moments $1,1/2,1/3,1/4,...$ because $\int_0^1 x^n \, dx=\frac 1{n+1}$.

My question is: is it always possible to find a function $f(x)$ such that $\int_0^1 f(x)^n \, dx = a_n$ where $a_n$ is an arbitrary sequence, for instance, Bernoulli numbers? If so, what function would be a representation of Bernoulli umbra?

Comment: Consider the simplest cast $a_0 =1$, $a_1 = 1$, and $a_k =0$ otherwise. $a_1 =1$ determines $f(x) = 1$,  but then this determines $a_k=1$ for $k >1$.

Comment: @TomCopeland hmm, no. $a_1=1$ does not determine $f(x)=1$.

Comment: @TomCopeland but I agree that a sequence with zeros at even positions cannot be represented this way.

Comment: There are many restrictions, for example $a_1^2\le a_2$, by Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: My bad, you're right. $\int_{0}^x f(t) dt = b_0 x + b_1 x^2/2! + ...$ if $f(x) = b_0 + b_1 x+b_2x^2/2! + \cdots$.

Comment: I scanned very quickly two papers that would likely have shown such a function for the Bernoullis, but did not find one.

Comment: @TomCopeland tried function $(2 x-1)^2-1$ as an example, got sequence $\frac{(-4)^n \Gamma (n+1)^2}{\Gamma (2 n+2)}$ with moments $\left\{-\frac{2}{3},\frac{8}{15},-\frac{16}{35},\frac{128}{315},-\frac{256}{693},...\right\}$

Comment: There would be less overhead (possibly irrelevant) to the question if it were more direct: "given a sequence $a_n$, is there a function $f$ on the unit interval such that $\int_0^1f^n =a_n$?" ?

Comment: @paulgarrett I just tried to include motivation. Also, the umbra with moments $\frac1{n+1}$ corresponts to the operator $\Delta D^{-1}$ while Bernoulli umbra corresponds to $D \Delta^{-1}$, so it is anti-Bernoulli umbra in a sense.

Comment: Can you refine your question? If it is "does every sequence $a_n$ arise in this way" the answer is clearly no as explained in the comments (there are many restrictions). But: can we specifically get the Bernoulli numbers seems more interesting. So focus on that question.

Comment: @SamHopkins I think, it is not productive to edit the question after each comment or partial answer.